# How to add request header parameter as a lookup variable in log4j for spring boot microservice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I am building a microservice using `Spring Boot` with multiple rest endpoints. Each request has a header named `track_number` with a unique value for each request. I am using log4j2.xml to set configuration of logging. and use `lombok` to initialize log in each class.

**Code Flow :**
*Controller->Service->Repo/Other*

I am getting the `track_number` in controller, I would like to have `track_number` in logs of Service and other mapper class each time I log. One way to achieve this is to pass `track_number` as parameter to all the methods where I am logging.

Is there a more cleaner way to achieve this? is it possible to create a log4j look up parameter for track number? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Check the [`ThreadContext` documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html).

Comment: Can you try exploring Sleuth or some other logging framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to acheive this using [ThreadContext](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html?force_isolation=true). I added the tracking number to ThreadContext map with key `TID` in the beginning of controller.

```
    ThreadContext.put("TID",trackingid);
```

and just before returning response entity I am clearing ThreadContext map `ThreadContext.clear();`

and used `%X{TID}` pattern in the `log4j2.xml` to look up the ThreadContext.

```
<Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
   %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}{GMT+3} %-5p %c{10}:%L TrackID: %X{TID} - %m%n
</Property>
```

Now all the logs have track id data.

Thank you [Piotr P Karwasz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11748454/piotr-p-karwasz?force_isolation=true) for pointing to ThreadContext solution.